# Unique identifier of the activity that is read from the Google Fit?

Tags: android, google-fit, google-fit-api

I'm trying to find a way to get the UID or such for each activity record (historical data via Fit API for Android) that I read from Google Fit.

Is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can check this documentation: [Work with the Fitness History](https://developers.google.com/fit/android/history#read_detailed_and_aggregate_data) to get most frequent activity of the user. First, you need to read data from the fitness history by [creating a subscription](https://developers.google.com/fit/android/record#subscribe_to_fitness_data) for each fitness data type you'd like to record. This enables your app to sync with data from other devices, and also allows for the passive recording of data on the device. Then create a [DataReadRequest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39737598/google-fit-api-activity-history#:%7E:text=Then%20create%20a-,DataReadRequest,-instance.%20You%20can) instance. You can see the sample code in the documentation.

The data request can specify multiple [data types](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/fitness/data/DataType#TYPE_STEP_COUNT_DELTA) to return, effectively combining multiple data queries into one call. With this, you can compare which activity the user used most

The Fit Android API has been deprecated and will be shut down by the end of 2024; therefore, I strongly suggest migrating from Fit to Health Connect. Refer to the [Migration Guide](https://developer.android.com/guide/health-and-fitness/health-connect-guidelines/migrate/migration-guide) for instructions on Health Connect migration.